# getting error in TypeScript : Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, stenciljs

Trying to add span element to a string by replacing the commas. But getting above error code in my jquery code.

for example What I am trying to accomplish:

```
this.prop.city == "los angeles, new york, boston"
```

then that string turns into:

```
<span>los angeles</span> <span>new york</span> <span>boston</span>
```

This is my code section it is based on stencil.js

The line causing the error is

```
        $('.tag').html($('.tag').html().split(', ').map(function(el) {return '<span>' + el + '</span>'}));
```

```
  @Component({
    tag: 'stencil-component-text',
})
export class stencilComponentText {
    @Prop() prop: any;

      componentDidLoad() {

        $('.tag').html($('.tag').html().split(', ').map(function(el) {return '<span>' + el + '</span>'}));
    }

       render() {
        if (this.prop.countryCode && this.prop.city) {
            if(this.prop.city.includes(',')){

                return  <span class="testing">{this.prop.countryCode} - <span class="tag">{this.prop.city}</span>, {this.prop.state}</span>
            } 
     }
```

Full error is as follows:

```
Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type
          'string | Element | Text | Comment | DocumentFragment | ((this:
          HTMLElement, index: number, oldhtml: string) => string | Element |
          Text | Comment | DocumentFragment)'. Type 'string[]' is not
          assignable to type 'string'.
```

Comment: Please consider publishing reproducable code exmaple, otherwise your question might  be closed because of lack of clarity. Just friendly advise

Comment: @captain-yossarian how does it look now?

Comment: looks much better now. What line causes an error? Imagine that you are the person who wants to answer, how would you reproduce your example without knowing the line of error and type of props?

Comment: Try to share your reproducable example here https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: The setup is  a bit confusing for a stencil component